# How to "flatten" list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flatten

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
test_dict = [{'id': 0, 'name': ['Jim'], 'lastname': ['kkk']}, {'id': 1, 'name': ['John'], 'lastname': ['lll']}]
test_dict


[{'id': 0, 'name': ['Jim'], 'lastname': ['kkk']},
 {'id': 1, 'name': ['John'], 'lastname': ['lll']}]
```

I would like to create another dictionary that will have as keys, the `id`s of the `test_dict`.

The output I am looking for, looks like this:

```
test_dict_f = {'0': {'name': ['Jim'], 'lastname': ['kkk']}, 
              '1': {'name': ['John'], 'lastname': ['lll']}}
test_dict_f

{'0': {'name': ['Jim'], 'lastname': ['kkk']},
 '1': {'name': ['John'], 'lastname': ['lll']}}
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this ?

Comment: what did you try already and why didn't it work?

Comment: I also want to point out that after the conversion, getting the first name goes from `test_dict[0]["name"][0]` to `test_dict_f["0"]["name"][0]`. The only different is the quotes around the first zero. Is that really what you want?

Comment: The main difference is that then I can access the `name` by using the `id`, which means that `test_dict_f['0']['name']` would give me `['Jim']` where as before I cannot do that

Comment: `test_dict_f['0']['name']` would give you `["Jim"]`, not `"Jim"`.

Comment: I also don't recommend converting your ints to strings, but that's just my preference

Comment: You are right, edited my comment. The essence is the same though.

Comment: What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? I see it as follows: 1. given a dictionary from the list, can you get the ID, and produce the modified dictionary without the ID? 2. given a list of key-value pairs, can you create a dictionary? So - where are you stuck?

Comment: @PaulH consider that in the actual data, the `id` values of the dictionaries might not be in sequential order, or 0-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in one line:

```
result = {str(i["id"]): {"name": i["name"], "lastname": i["lastname"]} for i in test_dict}
```

the result will be:

```
{'0': {'name': ['Jim'], 'lastname': ['kkk']},
 '1': {'name': ['John'], 'lastname': ['lll']}}
```

Comment: A slightly hackier way to drop 1 key would be `{ str(d['id']) : (d.pop('id'), d)[1]  for d in test_dict}`

Comment: it will raise `KeyError: 'id'` for sure.@AlexeyLarionov

Comment: I tested it, it won't. `str(d['id'])` is evaluated earlier

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it that doesn't rely on knowledge of any keys other than 'id'. Note that this is destructive:

```
test_dict = [{'id': 0, 'name': ['Jim'], 'lastname': ['kkk']}, {'id': 1, 'name': ['John'], 'lastname': ['lll']}]

test_dict_f = {}

for d in test_dict:
    id_ = d.pop('id')
    test_dict_f[str(id_)] = d

print(test_dict_f)
```

**Output:**

```
{'0': {'name': ['Jim'], 'lastname': ['kkk']}, '1': {'name': ['John'], 'lastname': ['lll']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_dict = [{'id': 0, 'name': ['Jim'], 'lastname': ['kkk']}, {'id': 1, 'name': ['John'], 'lastname': ['lll']}]


pp({i["id"]: {k:v for k,v in i.items() if k!="id"} for i in test_dict})
or event much funnier: 
pp({i["id"]: i|{"id":i["id"]} for i in test_dict})

{0: {'name': ['Jim'], 'lastname': ['kkk']},
 1: {'name': ['John'], 'lastname': ['lll']}}
```